# why this code always enters into catch block?

Tags: java, exception

I am creating a simple Calculator. Whenever i try to perform any operation it enters into catch block. here is code. textFields are as follows:
textfield(to show calculation),textField1(to enter operand),textfield_1(to show Solution)

```
button = new JButton("+");
    button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                ans=Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                s=Double.toString(ans)+"+";
                textField.setText(s);
                reset();
                operand=Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
                ans+=operand;
                textField_1.setText(Double.toString(ans));
            }catch(Exception x){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a valid argument");

            }

        }
    });
    button.setBounds(43, 115, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    button.setToolTipText("ADDITION");
//reset textField1  
public void reset(){
    textField1.setText("");
}
```

//............//

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at gui.Calcu$2.actionPerformed(Calcu.java:92)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If your question is only why the execution goes in to catch block then the answer is there is an exception in the try block that's the reason. If you want to fix the exception please post the stack trace.

Comment: Add `x.printStackTrace();` to the catch block, then examine a console output, and you will find a reason of the error.

Comment: hey i just want to make a calculator like  windows. i am a new bee plz help here.old calculations are displayed in textField which  is uneditable.

Comment: Replace Exception with NumberFormatException since you want to go to the catch block only when the two values can not be converted to doubles.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace. The problem is not otherwise apparent to us from the code you've posted. Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Now that we have a stacktrace, which part of the error is confusing? `NumberFormatException: empty String` ... `at Double.parseDouble` ... `as Calcu$2.actionPerformed`. So, obviously `textField1.getText()` returns an empty string, that is *"why this code always enters into catch block"*, to quote your own title. As for why `getText()` returns empty string, that cannot be determined from the code displayed here.

Comment: Wheat does the reset() method do?

Comment: it clears the textField1 to enter next operand in very same textField

Comment: Because you use `reset()` function when click button. This make `textField1.getText()` return empty string. So I think `operand=Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());` would throw exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
reset();//this makes the textField1 hold an empty String 
operand=Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
```

So when you are trying to read and parse a Double from it you are geting a NumberFormatException because you can not convert an empty String into a Double.

One solution to your problem is to create a second JTextField and let the user write the first number he wants to add to the first textField and the second one to the second.Then, when he presses the button to see the result read each number separately, process them and show the result to the screen(either on one of your two textFileds or you could use a third one to display the result).

On the other hand, if you want to have a single textField to handle the user input, you could declare a variable sum outside of all the methods(make it global) and each time you press the "+" button add the value to sum and when the user is done typing numbers just display its String value to the screen.

Additional information on how the [event-driven](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) programming works.

Comment: thanks i understood but can you tell me way to clear textField and enter next operand in same  textField

Comment: @urbanlegend I tryied to give you an idea of what you should do, but i am not going to tell you exactly how to do it because if you sit down and think about the problem for a while, this will help you understand some things about event- driven programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your button click listner,

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
              final double val1 = Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
              ans = val1;
              s = Double.toString(ans) + "+";
              textField.setText(s);
              reset();
              operand = val1;
              ans += operand;
              textField_1.setText(Double.toString(ans));
          }catch(Exception x){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a valid argument");

          }

      }
  });
```

Comment: Operand=val1 gives operand1=operand2